# Read specific line from text file using $GET, then echo it

Tags: php, get, echo

I have a text file which is already created and appended by user and I am using this format to append it. New line after every input and separated by semicolon:

Movie Title1; Movie Rating1; Plot1;

Movie Title2; Movie Rating2; Plot2;

Movie Title3; Movie Rating3; Plot3;

Etc. etc.

I have managed to fix the above and now I want to read a specific line from the text file then echo it. This specific line is to be found through $GET parameter and based on Movie Title.

For example I click on a link, in this case a title from a movie, then I get the title name through $GET: movies.php to change to movies.php?title=MovieTitle. And then I get this current Movie Title name and read this specific line and echo it. Here is my code:

```
//Writes input from user to movies.txt
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $title = $_POST['movieTitle'];
        $rating = $_POST['movieRatings'];
        $plot = $_POST['plot'];


    $handle = fopen('movies.txt', 'a');
    $names_array = array("$title","$rating","$plot");
    $string = implode(';', $names_array);
    fwrite($handle, $string."\n");          
    fclose($handle);
    }   
    ?>

//Reads line from movies.txt and adds it to a li, with movie title becoming a link
<?php
    $filename = 'movies.txt';

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

    $datain = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); 

    $lines = explode ("\n",trim($datain));
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        list($title,$rating,$plot) = explode(";",$line,3);
        echo '<li><a href="movies.php?title='.$title.'">'.$title.'</a><span>'.$rating.'</span></li>';
    }
    ?>//So far so good

//And now I want to read title name, and based on the
//title name find a specific line with rating and plot 
//which belongs to current clicked movie title...
<?php
if (isset($_GET["title"])) {
    $readin = file('movies.txt');

    foreach ($readin as $fname) 
    $names_array = explode(';', $fname);
    {
            echo '<h1>'.$names_array[0]./*MovietitleName*/'</h1>''<h2>'.$rating.'</h2>'.$plot;//So I want to echo the specific "movieTitle movie, movieRating and moviePlot". What I've done so far is wrong, I need help here! 
    }
    }
?>
```

So I want to echo it out with movie title being in  and and movie rating  .I hope you understand my question, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered to use a database? It's not hard and would do you good.

Comment: No I am not considering a database. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First off you have errors in your syntax. Secondly this is what a database is for your solution is not going to scale. However to get it to work do something like....

```
if (isset($_GET["title"])) {
  $readin = file('movies.txt');

  foreach ($readin as $fname) 
  {
     $names_array = explode(';', $fname);//this has to go here
     if($_GET['title']===$names_array[0]){//only echo if the title mathces
        echo '<h1>'.$names_array[0]./*MovietitleName*/'</h1>''<h2>'.$names_array[1].'</h2>'.$names_array[2];
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I dont get the current lines rating echo'd out... It echoes out a different rating.

Comment: Use $names_array[1] to echo the rating and $names_array[2] for the plot.

Comment: As @Emil said. If you are confused what your `$names_array` contains then do `print_r($names_array);` to inspect it

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
if (isset($_GET["title"])) {
  $readin = file('movies.txt');

  foreach ($readin as $fname) 
  {
     $names_array = explode(';', $fname);//this has to go here
     if($_GET['title']==$names_array[0]){
        echo '<h1>'.$names_array[0].'</h1><h2>'.$names_array[1].'</h2>'.$names_array[2];
     }
  }
}
```